JCombobox need to toggle again to execute method
I'm working on a project and I use a JComboBox, when I'm choosing an Item, it executes two times, and to execute my method inside it selectItemchange Icon I need to select the item and click again the Jcombobox for my method to be executed
this is my method
here's where I got some fields
 void change_seat_list(String rt) throws SQLException, ParseException{
        left_seat_panel.removeAll();
        mid_seat_panel.removeAll();
        right_seat_panel.removeAll();
        st1="";
        
        ResultSet rs2 =  stmt.executeQuery(qry);
       
        while(rs2.next()){
            if(rs2.getString(1).equals(sm_mtitle.getText()) 
                    && rs2.getString(4).equals(rt) ){
                st1 = rs2.getString(9);
            }
        }
       
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry3);
        ResultSet rsn = rs;
        while(rsn.next()){

            if(rsn.getString(1).equals(st1)){
                String cn="";
                ImageIcon seat_icon = new ImageIcon("seat.png");
                JRadioButton jr = new JRadioButton();
                if(rsn.getString(5).equals("A")){
                    jr.setBackground(Color.white);
                }
                else{
                    jr.setBackground(new Color(255,204,102));
                }
                jr.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                        if(!(jr.getBackground().equals(Color.cyan)) && 
                            !(jr.getBackground().equals(new Color(255,204,102)))){
                            jr.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                            seat_choices.add(jr.getText());
                            System.out.println("Added to list");
                        }
                        else if(!(jr.getBackground().equals(new Color(255,204,102)))){
                            jr.setBackground(Color.white);
                            seat_choices.remove(jr.getText());
                            System.out.println("removed to list");
                        }
                    }
                });
                if(rs.getString(3).equals("L")){
                    cn = cn+"L"+rs.getString(4);
                    jr.setText(cn); jr.setIcon(seat_icon);
                    left_seat_panel.add(jr);
                    //System.out.println("Nalagay sa left");
                }
                else if(rs.getString(3).equals("M")){
                    cn = cn+"M"+rs.getString(4);
                    jr.setText(cn);jr.setIcon(seat_icon);
                    mid_seat_panel.add(jr);
                    //System.out.println("Nalagay sa mid");
                }
                else if(rs.getString(3).equals("R")){
                    cn = cn+"R"+rs.getString(4);
                    jr.setText(cn);jr.setIcon(seat_icon);
                    right_seat_panel.add(jr);//System.out.println("Nalagay sa right");
                }
                left_seat_panel.repaint();
                mid_seat_panel.repaint();
                right_seat_panel.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

this is how I call it in an event
    private void av_timeItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                         
        
        if(!(evt.getItem().toString().equals("unavailable"))){
            String time_ch = evt.getItem().toString();
            try {
                time_ch = convert_12hr_to_24hr(time_ch);
                change_seat_list(time_ch);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Seat_Management.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Seat_Management.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            
        }

    }   

I try different events and I also try to use a Jbutton to execute a method but it's still need the JCombobox to be clicked. I expect that when I change selected Item it will execute my method instantly
